# Reuse the same socket to send and receive (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, port, bind, listen

I have written a simple script to send and receive messages using the Python socket module. I want to first send a message using `sendMsg` and then receive a response using `listen`. `sendMsg` works fine but when my server sends a response I receive the error:

"[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

I close the socket connection in `sendMsg` and then try to bind it in `listen`, but it's at this line that the error is produced. Please could someone show me what I am doing wrong!

```
import socket

port = 3400
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), port))

def sendMsg():

    print("\nSending message:\n\n")
    msg = ("Sample text").encode("utf-8")
    s.send(msg)
    s.close()

def listen():

    s.bind(("", port))
    s.listen(1)

    serverSocket, info = s.accept()
    print("Connection from", info, "\n")
    while 1:
        try:            
            buf = bytearray(4000)
            view = memoryview(buf)
            bytes = serverSocket.recv_into(view, 4000)
            if bytes:
                stx = view[0]
                Size = view[1:3]
                bSize = Size.tobytes()
                nTuple = struct.unpack(">H", bSize)
                nSize = nTuple[0]
                message = view[0:3+nSize]
                messageString = message.tobytes().decode("utf-8").strip()
                messageString = messageString.replace("\x00", "")
            else:
                break
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Socket timeout.")
            break

sendMsg()

listen()
```

**Note:** I have implemented `listen` in a separate client and used the line

`s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 3)`

before `s.bind()` and `s.connect()`. This works OK. It would be nice to have it all in one client though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs the [socket.close()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) will close the socket and no further operations are allowed on it.

So in your code this line `s.close()` is closing the socket.

Because of that the `s.bind(("", port))` will not work as the socket `s` is already closed!

Comment: I see, thank you. The problem then is that I get "[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied" at `s.bind`. I tried using `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 3)` here to allow for reuse with no luck..

Comment: Try `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` before `s.bind()`.

Comment: Yes I think that has fixed it! Thanks for your help